# Latest posts by category — how to exclude current post?

Tags: posts, categories, recent-posts, listing

This is the code I use to display the 4 most recent posts under the category the current post belongs to (right below the current post):

```
<?php if (is_single()) : ?>
    <?php
        $count = 0;
        $aahan_category = get_the_category();
        $aahan_category = get_term_by( 'name', $aahan_category[0]->cat_name, 'category');
        $some_featured_posts = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => $aahan_category->slug, 'posts_per_page' => 4));
        while ($some_featured_posts->have_posts()):
            $some_featured_posts->the_post();
            $count++;
            $no_margin = (2 == $count || 4 == $count) ? ' no-margin-right' : '';
    ?>

    <div class="latest-category-posts-image-t<?php echo $no_margin; ?>">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
        <h1 class="latest-category-posts-text"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </a>
    </div>

    <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In case it matters, I added this code in `content-single.php`. The code basically shows the featured images (post-thumbnail) of the 4 most recent posts under the category the current post belongs to, along with their titles.

Now the question is, if the current post is among the `n` most recent posts (`n = 4` as per my code), how do I exclude it from the listing?

**PS:** Although it goes without saying, it would be great if you can show how the code I use could be *optimized*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`post__not_in` parameter of `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) to exclude an array of post IDs from the query.

[`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) returns an array of term objects, so the `get_term_by` is redundant. Also `is_single()` will always be true in `content-single.php` (*not strictly speaking true but only not so if you are interferring with the template selection*).

(Finally, in your example, if you have at most 4 posts, then `(2==$count || 4==$count)` is equivalent to `($count%2 == 0)`)

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    $cat = get_the_category();
    if( $cat ){

        $featured_posts = new WP_Query(array( 
              'post__not_in'=>array(get_the_ID()),
              'category_name' => $cat->slug, 
              'posts_per_page' => 4
         ));

         while ( $featured_posts->have_posts() ): $featured_posts->the_post();
                 $count++;
                 $no_margin = ($count%2 == 0) ? ' no-margin-right' : '';
             ?>
                 <div class="latest-category-posts-image-t<?php echo $no_margin; ?>">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                        <h1 class="latest-category-posts-text"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                 </a>
                </div>
            <?php
         endwhile;
         wp_reset_postdata();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Need I say it? Great answer, as always. Thanks! :)

Comment: Isn't the closing brace `}` for the conditional tag missing?

Comment: ye... ahem, I mean no...